# The default value of a local variable in c is a garbage value,right? Then why am always getting same output?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

```
void func();

int main() {
  func();
  func();
  func();
}

void func() {
  int a;
  printf("%d\n",++a);
}
```

When I run this C code in GCC compiler I get output as

```
1 
2
3
```

Why does this happen without using the `static` keyword?

Comment: It is unspecified/undefined behavoiur. Plenty of duplicates out there.

Comment: As far as "why I get 1 2 3" question goes, here is a [very good reading on a closely related subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794).

Comment: Is it rubbish-collection day?   I forgot to take out wheelie bins out:(

Comment: unspecified behavior means the implementation can do whatever it wants. including setting it to zero if it feels like it.

Answer (score 5):

There are two cases to consider:

- If the local variable is `static`, it is initialized with zeros; `static` variables of pointer type are set to `NULL`
- If the local variable is automatic, it is not initialized at all. Reading from such variable without assigning to it first is undefined behavior.

Comment: Isn't nullptr only for C++?

Comment: Rolled back just in case: I owe @dasblinkenlight a drink if I ruined this answer ;-)

Answer (score 4):

According to the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is **indeterminate**.

and (3.19.2)

> 1 indeterminate value either an unspecified value or a trap
>   representation

So there is no default value for objects with automatic storage duration. They have indeterminate values.

Take into account that the notions of local variable and of variable with automatic storage duration are different. For example in this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 10;

void f()
{
    extern int x;
    printf( "%d\n", x );
}

int main( void )
{
    f();
}
```

the variable x declared in function f like

```
    extern int x;
```

is a local variable of the function. But it has external linkage and denotes the same variable as the global. x.

The program output will be

```
10
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple program. A local variable is placed on the stack. No one can guarantee what value will be on the stack at the beginning of the program. But since you call the same function which increments the local variable `a`, the variable is incremented on the stack. Then you call the same function again so it allocates the same place on the stack which already has the value of `a` from the previous time. If you call any other function between `func ()` in the `int main()` (for example `printf`), you will get different results.

Comment: You correctly say "No one can guarantee what value will be on the stack at the beginning of the program". But, on almost _all_ systems, the initial value will be zero. (For various reasons: e.g. a previous program may have left a password in memory.)